# Arduino - Progamming issue

Tags: serial, debugging

my first post here.

Anyway I'm working on a Simon Says game.
I have a weird bug with the function that reads button input.

This is the code:

```
int deBounce(int count){
  int pressed=-1;
  int laastButtons[3]; // save the previous deBounce read.
  for(int x; x<4; x++)
  {
    laastButtons[x] = lastButtons[x];
    lastButtons[x] = !digitalRead(button[x]);
    if(lastButtons[x] == true)
    {
      delay(50);
      lastButtons[x] = !digitalRead(button[x]);
      if(lastButtons[x] == 1){ pressed = x;}
      nt("Pressed!, Button ID: ");nt(x); nt(" pressed:  ");nt(pressed); nt(" state "); ntln(lastButtons[x]);
    }
  }
  if((lastButtons[0] + lastButtons[1] + lastButtons[2] + lastButtons[3]) > 1)
  {
    ntln("ERROR: dont press more than one button at a time. ");
  }
  if( ((lastButtons[0] + lastButtons[1] + lastButtons[2] + lastButtons[3]) == 1 ) && !laastButtons[pressed] && (pressed != -1) ) { 
    pressButtons[count] = pressed;
    nt("Pressed!, ID: ");nt(count); nt(" Button ID ");ntln(pressed);
    return count++;
  }else return count;
}
```

This is what I recieve in the Serial Monitor if I press one of the buttons.

> Pressed!, Button ID: 3 pressed: -1 state 1

How is that possible? Note the lines where that line is printed and the line above it.
Seems like that if should run, but the line pressed = x; doesn't function.
Note that, nt and ntln are just a short for Serial.print.
I have this weird bug and sometimes it seems like the chip is glitching!

Another question is- I tried attaching interrupt and it didn't worked,
Is it possible that my board is not compatiable with them? (It's not original).

Thanks.

EDIT:

After Majenko helped me figure it out,
The thing that created the bug was that I expected a x==0, but I didn't define it in the for loop.

Before:

```
for(int x; x<4; x++)
```

After:

```
for(int x=0; x<4; x++)
```

Thanks again Majenko!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int laastButtons[3]; // save the previous deBounce read.
for(int x; x<4; x++)
{
   laastButtons[x] = lastButtons[x];
```

Well, there's a common bug right away.  An array with three slices, numbered 0, 1 and 2, and you're accessing them with a loop that counts from 0 to 3.

Spot the error.

Also, in the for loop, what number does it start counting from?

And now for your "bug".  This block of code:

```
if(lastButtons[x] == true)
{
  delay(50);
  lastButtons[x] = !digitalRead(button[x]);
  if(lastButtons[x] == 1){ pressed = x;}
  nt("Pressed!, Button ID: ");nt(x); nt(" pressed:  ");nt(pressed); nt(" state "); ntln(lastButtons[x]);
}
```

I think you have it slightly wrong.  Let's convert it into plain english:

- If button is pressed:

  - Delay 50 ms
  - Read button again
  - If button is pressed:

    - Set *pressed* to the button number
  - Print the button message

Note the indenting, which highlights what gets executed for what IF statement.  The print is going to happen regardless of the setting of the *pressed* variable.

I think the structure you wanted is:

- If button is pressed:

  - Delay 50 ms
  - Read button again
  - If button is pressed:

    - Set *pressed* to the button number
    - Print the button message

In that layout the second If is controlling both the setting of the *pressed* variable as well as whether or not to print the Pressed! message.

```
if(lastButtons[x] == 1){ pressed = x;}
```

That line is saying "If last buttons X is 1, then set pressed to X. That is all it is doing. Nothing more, nothing less.